# SkyDrive API access code sometime works sometime does not works

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, onedrive

I am trying to access skydrive content from my code. the following code worked before but suddently it stopped executing the second result. Not sure what microsoft has done in behind! Please help. Please not that the scopes are valid and my app for win8 has got the access.

```
var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
var scopes = new[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive", "wl.basic" };
Task<LiveLoginResult> resultTask = authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
var client = new LiveConnectClient(resultTask.Result.Session);
dynamic result1 = client.GetAsync("me/skydrive");


dynamic result2 = result1.Result;

result1 = client.GetAsync("me/skydrive");
result2 = result1.Result;
```

Thanks
Kajal

Comment: If it's a store app, you may want to use `await` instead of blocking on `Result` or you may not get it ok'd for the store. That said, I see nothing _obviously_ wrong with that code snippet unless `dynamic` is causing problems. I'd try with `var` instead.

Comment: The status remains "WaitingForActivation" and the session scopes in the local window shows "null".. still no luck, I was running it from last 2 months and all was going well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is lacking async/await.

If your code is within an event body then use `async void` as return type otherwise `async Task<T>` where `T` class name of return type data.

> var authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
>
> var scopes = new[] { "wl.signin", "wl.skydrive", "wl.basic" };
>
> Task resultTask = **await** authClient.LoginAsync(scopes);
>
> var client = new LiveConnectClient(resultTask.Result.Session);
>
> dynamic result1 = **await** client.GetAsync("me/skydrive");
>
> dynamic result2 = result1.Result;
>
> result1 =  **await** client.GetAsync("me/skydrive");
>
> result2 = result1.Result;

Comment: +1 Unsure if it fixes the problem, but this is definitely a better way than blocking.